# 2d animation on html5 canvas using a vector and speed

Tags: javascript, animation, vector, html5, html-canvas

Im moving a starship from one location to the other. In creating a vector, normalize and magnitude it.

Lets assume my vector looks like this

```
Vector
    x: 156,
    y: -90,
    m:  180.0000000546,
    nx:  0.8661855860486004,
    ny: -0.49972245348957717,
```

The way im animating the ships movement currently is:

```
            if (! action.animated){
                if (action.type == "move"){
                    if (game.ships[i].actions[j].v.m > 0){ 
// v is the Vector above !
                       game.ships[i].x += action.v.nx;
                       game.ships[i].y += action.v.ny;
                       game.ships[i].actions[j].v.m--;
                    }
                    else {
                       game.ships[i].actions[j].animated = true;
                    }
```

So basicly, im using `requestanimationframe` and a loop to move the starship by what equals 1 magnitude / **1 unit length (px) per frame**.
So far it is working (but for the fact that the vessel animates one more magnitude than it should).

However, assuming i have **two starships** and one has a vector **magnitude of 180 while the other has a magnitude of 200** and im animating both at the same time, how can i create an animation that will move the faster starships quicker, i.e. **both starships should** begin moving and **end moving in the same frame** ?

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use the magnitude. Because all it does is complicate things. Use a constant number (aka frameRate) that will determine the speed of change in frames.
You can also check out this answer: [Sprite Animation Best Practices](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1434/sprite-animation-best-practices/1436#1436)

The above method will allow you to have the same animation that can be used by multiple sprites. Instead of each sprite having it's own animations. Hope this helps :D

Comment: Give me a code example that replace the approach i describe above.
Also, why would using Magnitude complicate things ? On reddit (tm) i was explicitly told to USE Magnitude !
Also, how does your anwser help me with my Magnitude/Dist 180/200 problem ?